# Join with SELECT MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, join

I need a way to join a table with the results of a SELECT query, and I'm facing some difficulty to do that ...

There are 3 tables:

food_shops

```
id, name, slug
```

categories_food_shops

```
id, id_category, id_food_shop
```

categories

```
id, name, slug
```

How can I do to show a result with: `food_shop.id`, `food_shop.name`, `categorie.slug`
based on the categories_food_shops table? that contains a registry of the shop and their category?

so far I was able to do this, but it gets

> Unknown column 'fs.id' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT fs.id, fs.slug, fs.name
FROM food_shops fs
JOIN  
(
    SELECT *
    FROM categories_food_shops cfs
    WHERE cfs.id_food_shop = fs.id
) AS cfs ON categories.id = cfs.id_catedory
```

Any help would be very appreciated, I'm new to this join statements

Comment: try move the inner where cfs.id_food_shop = fs.id into your on clause?

Comment: Please post some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: PM 77-1 I told there, i want to get the id, name, slug from food_shops and the slug from categories, based on a relationship table (categories_food_shops)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    food_shops.id, food_shops.name, categories.slug
FROM food_shops

INNER JOIN categories_food_shops
ON food_shops.id = categories_food_shops.id_food_shop

INNER JOIN categories
ON categories_food_shops.id_category = categories.id
```

You can then use a `WHERE` statement at the end to display food shops with a specific id, or with a similar name, etc.

Comment: I'm not begging, it's actually a good thing seeing people mark off questions as answered as it tells other users that he no longer needs help with this question. But I can see where you're coming from.